# Error accessing localhost:port through bash on ubuntu on windows

Tags: ruby, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to access connection to a database through aptible and when I try to do that , I get an error that seems to be related to permission/access .

```
Creating tunnel...r 
/opt/aptible-toolbelt/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aptible-cli-0.7.3/lib/aptible/cli/helpers/tunnel.rb:53\
  :in `rescue in start': Tunnel did not come up, is something else listening on port 60387? (RuntimeError)
bind: Address already in use
(8ミ | INFO: Connecting to database...
(8ミ | ERROR: 403 (access_denied)
```

I tried editing the file to use different ports but the same error persists .

It seems to be erroring out in connecting to localhost:portnumber .

Could someone help me here ?

This is very important for me as I'm working on a important project .

Thanks 
Nanditha

Comment: show the command you are entering?

Comment: This is the command - aptible db:tunnel sqldb-dev

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug that looked like this was fixed at one point:

https://github.com/aptible/aptible-cli/issues/47

Try a newer version of aptible?

Comment: I installed the latest one just couple of days ago . So I'm pretty sure there is nothing latest I can try here . Is there any other workaround I can have for this one ?